# JSF: h:datatable problem

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I have problem with h:datatable tag in JSF. I don't know, why my datatable is not showing on my page. Some advices?

Here is my code:

```
<h:dataTable  rows="2" var="deb" value="#{debCredTab.rows}">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Debet
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{deb.debet}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Credit
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{deb.credit}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            DebCredSum
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:inputText value="#{deb.debetCreditSum}" />
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

And here is my output:

```
<table rules="all">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The question is: why? I forgot something? Why my table is not showing on the page?

Comment: What is the content in debCredTab.rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would test to make sure your rows is not returning null:

```
<h:outputText value="#{debCredTab.rows eq null}" />
```

I would then check to see if the number of rows is zero.

Comment: Actually they are, but, as far as i understood, i can collect info from datatable, not only insert. Is it correct?

Comment: eh? you can collect data if you have inputs. and you don't have.

Comment: You will need an empty row to add data to. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355614/datatable-containing-inputtext-is-it-possible-with-jsf-custom-component/356740#356740

Comment: Thanks McDowell! Your post helped me!